# VB.net, multiple class access to one variable string

Tags: vb.net, string, constructor

What is the best way to access the string which is in one class from others ?
I have one class Settings, which loading multiple variables like ( model, serial, user, password etc ), i would like to access this string from other classes which needs some specified settings.

```
Public Class Settings
    Public SerialNumber As String
    Public ModelName As String
    Public SystemVer As String
    Public System_Ver As String
    Public BiosVen As String

    Sub SetSomeThing

        SerialNumber = "12313"
        ModelName = "Toshiba"
        SystemVer = "Windows 8"
        System_Ver = "PRO"
        BiosVen = "AMI"

    End Sub

End Class

Class Load

    Sub get_Bios
        Dim Settings As Settings = New Settings()

        Dim serial_number = Settings.SerialNumber 'Doesnt works, it's empty string ;(

    End Sub

End Class
```

Ok so i have some multiple classes, where i need different things from the Setting Class, what is the best way to access those values ? When i'm trying to do it like in the example i have always empty strings. Ofcourse there is a lots of this variables this is only very poor example.

Comment: You need to use the same instance.

Comment: You haven't called `settings.SetSomething` in your code.  Each `new Settings()` creates a new copy - and you need to store and pass that copy around to any parts of the code that want to use the same settings.

Comment: good learning start for you http://www.dotnetperls.com/property-vbnet

Comment: It's very important to understand the difference between a type definition, a type variable, and a type instance. Until distinguishing among these things is second nature to you, you will struggle to be an effective programmer.

Comment: Thanks for tips, i have resolve my problem by adding Shared type to the Public variables.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one instance of your settings then you can create a structure like this ...

```
Friend Class Form1
    Public Class Settings
        Public Shared SerialNumber As String = ""
        Public Shared ModelName As String = ""
        Public Shared SystemVer As String = ""
        Public Shared System_Ver As String = ""
        Public Shared BiosVen As String = ""
    End Class

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Settings.BiosVen = "mybios vendor"
        MessageBox.Show(Settings.BiosVen)
        Dim p As New otherclass
        p.MySub()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim newForm2 As New Form2
        newForm2.Show()

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class otherclass
    Public Sub MySub()
        MessageBox.Show(Form1.Settings.BiosVen)
    End Sub
End Class
```

if you want to reference this in another form, you can do it like the `OtherClass` above

**Form2 Code**

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MessageBox.Show(Form1.Settings.BiosVen)
    End Sub
End Class
```

However if you have multiple instances of the settings structure - for example a list of different computer settings in your `Form1` class then instead of making the structure a  public property, you should make the `List` of settings public - like this

```
Friend Class Form1

    Public Class Settings
        Public SerialNumber As String
        Public ModelName As String
        Public SystemVer As String
        Public System_Ver As String
        Public BiosVen As String

        Public Sub New()
            SerialNumber = ""
            ModelName = ""
            SystemVer = ""
            System_Ver = ""
            BiosVen = ""
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Shared Property computersSettings() As New List(Of Settings)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim newSettings As New Settings
        computersSettings.Add(newSettings)
        MessageBox.Show(computersSettings(0).BiosVen)
        computersSettings(0).BiosVen = "my bios vendor"
        Dim p As New otherclass
        p.MySub()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class otherclass
    Public Sub MySub()
        MessageBox.Show(Form1.computersSettings(0).BiosVen)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**With appropriate changed to the Form2 Code**

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MessageBox.Show(Form1.computersSettings(0).BiosVen)
    End Sub
End Class
```